# Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors. (ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm try to create a trigger who check if a teacher already teach this class in this session:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER C3
BEFORE INSERT ON classGroup
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE teach NUMBER(10);
BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) INTO teach;
    from classGroup
    WHERE classId = :new.classId
    AND teacherId = :new.teacherId,
    AND sessionId = :new.sessionId;
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,'you cant teach 2 time the same class');

exception
    when no_data_found then
        -- do insert
END;
/
```

but i'm always getting this message :

```
Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.
```

the table Classgroup contain: classId, groupId, sessionId, teacherId, desc

Comment: whats that comma and semicolon in the SELECT-statement

Comment: When you get that message, do `show errors` if your client supports that, or query the `user_errors` view, to see what the actual compilation errors are.

Comment: Turo already said what the problems are.

Comment: Even when you fix the syntax, it won't work the way you'd like.  Count always returns a value, which you aren't checking.  So, you're just executing the query and then throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic syntax error.

There is a ; after teach and a , after :new.teacherId

```
SELECT count(*) INTO teach
    from classGroup
    WHERE classId = :new.classId
    AND teacherId = :new.teacherId
    AND sessionId = :new.sessionId;
```

Comment: Ironic that this answer was chosen, because I don't think it will ever raise a data-not-found exception.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, just focussed on the error the OP was getting.

Answer (score 3):

A trigger is unnecessary.  Simply define a unique index or constraint:

```
create unique index unq_classGroup_3 on classGroup(classId, teacherId, sessionId);
```

This should be more efficient than a trigger.

Comment: But I think he wants to raise a message to the client on any attempt to add an existing class.

Comment: @JCDecary.   Gordon Linoff and  T Gray are right. First this wont work right. And if you repair "select 1 into teach ... " on every insert will be one exception raised which is expensive. And third the efficient solutions is an unique index. You can catch than the exception in your application (DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX) and show a custom error message to the user.